# Django Show Image in HTML

Tags: html, django, image, hyperlink, show

I am new to Django and want to show an image in HTML which is identified by an item's link being clicked in a table. The ID is given when a link is clicked. **HTML:**

```
<div id="link-product">
 <a id= "product-clicked" href="/prod_details/{item.id }}"> {{ item.product }} 
 </a>
 </div>
```

**VIEWS:**

```
def list_details(request,info_id):
    active_user = request.user
    product_image = Item_Model.objects.values_list('image').filter(id=info_id)
    return render(request,'prod_details.html', {'active_user': active_user, 'product_image': product_image})
```

Then it will go to the next page and the HTML should receive that item's ID and display its image accordingly. **HTML:**

```
    <div id="info-box-container">
    <img id= "product-image" src = "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product_image }}" />
    </div>
```

But when I do this, the image does not show. I am definitely missing some process. How can I get this to work as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values_list` returns a list of tuples but not the single value.  Change your query to:

```
product_image = Item_Model.objects.filter(id=info_id) \
                                  .values_list('image', flat=True).first()
```